# Need to correctly set the position of timestamp inside a bubble message, like Telegram. Swift

Tags: swift, message

I need to find a way to correctly position the timestamp label of my bubble message under the message label or on the right, based on the message content. To be clear I want to replicate the behavior of telegram, whatsapp etc. I have already tried to use the NSAttributedString and the boundingRect of NSLayoutManager to get the frame of the last 3 letters and than move the timestamp label based on the intersection of this one with the frame of the last 3 letters of the message but with no results.

Thank you in advance,
Arcangelo

This is the extension I use to generate the red rect frame showed in the picture

```
extension UILabel {
func boundingRect(forCharacterRange range: NSRange) -> CGRect? {
    guard let text = text else { return nil }
    
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: text)

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    var glyphRange = NSRange()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: bounds.size)
    
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    layoutManager.characterRange(forGlyphRange: range, actualGlyphRange: &glyphRange)

    return layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer)
}
```

Here I use the previous extension, to check the intersection

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    guard let timestampCount = timestampLabel.text?.count, timestampCount > 0,
       let bodyCount = bodyLabel.text?.count, bodyCount > 0 else { return }
       
    guard let text = bodyText, text.count > 2 else { return }
    
    let sublayer = CALayer()
    sublayer.borderWidth = 1
    sublayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            
    var boundingRect = bodyLabel.boundingRect(forCharacterRange: NSRange(location: text.count-2, length: 2))!
    boundingRect = convert(boundingRect, from: self)
    
    sublayer.frame = boundingRect
    
    bodyLabel.layer.sublayers?.first?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    bodyLabel.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
    
    bodyLabel.attributedText = bodyText?.attributedStringWithColorSize(color: UIColor.red , size: 15)

    if sublayer.frame.intersects(timestampLabel.frame)
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            timestampLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyLabel.bottomAnchor),
            timestampLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: containerView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Here is the result I have, as you can see I generate the red frame and check if it intersect the timestamp label, but the position is not correct

[image: Here is the result I have, as you can see I generate the red frame and check if it intersect the timestamp label, but the position is not correct]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have edited my question, hope to have been real now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should change the approach and define a custom view with a vertical `UIStackView` as parent and two `UILabel` as children.

Comment: @LucaPizzini I think that I haven't completely explained my problem. The timestamp of the label need to be positioned under the message, or on the right, or on the bottom left corner of the message, based on the message content. So it is not simply a problem oh stack view